Is there something wrong with my tomato plant?
2 days ago I got this small fruited tomato baby boomer plant. It was already potted and today I noticed there are quite a few dead leaves and some of the leaves have white spots and the bottoms of the main stems have a brown tint to them.
Is there something wrong with it or is there something I should do?






Hi Kristy, welcome to the site.  I've gone ahead and edited our pictures in so people don't have to follow the link.   Hopefully a tomato guru passes by soon :-)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community "...there are quite a few dead leaves and some of the leaves have white spots and the bottoms of the main stems have a brown tint to them.  Is there something wrong with it or is there something I should do?"
